# Ruby 'Go To Definition' not working in VS Code for methods defined inside a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code

## Issue

For support of Ruby, I'm using the VS Code extension listed below. I'm having trouble with the 'Go To Definition' command for methods defined within a block

```
module Abc
  module DefExtensions
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    included do
      def foo1() end # this gets ignored
    end

    User.new {
      def foo2() end
    }
    end

    def foo3
      def obj.bar() end # this gets ignored
    end
  end
end
```

## Extension

```
Name: Ruby
Id: rebornix.ruby
Description: Ruby language support and debugging for Visual Studio Code
Version: 0.28.1
Publisher: Peng Lv
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rebornix.Ruby
```

Facing the same issue with Solargraph too

```
Name: Ruby Solargraph
Id: castwide.solargraph
Description: A Ruby language server featuring code completion, intellisense, and inline documentation
Version: 0.24.0
Publisher: Castwide
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=castwide.solargraph
```

I've reported an [issue](https://github.com/HookyQR/ruby-method-locate/issues/2) to ruby-method-locate which is used by the extension to support 'Go To Definition'

**Is there a fix or solution for the aforementioned issue?**

Comment: why post images of source code text? Very hard to type over and try